# Wrong webkit-tap-highlight-color behavior when page as web standalone app

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, ios5, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm trying to remove the highlight on tap of a web page in the iPad with the css

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

This works great when using directly the browser in my iPad2. However if I move the page to a web app, with the a nice big icon, the behavior is not any longer working. Weirdo no ?

Setting

document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";

as pointed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900285/ios-4-3-uiwebview-webkit-user-selectnone-problem) does not work

Some ideas, hints are welcomed

Comment: Have you tried applying -webkit-tap-highlight-color and -webkit-touch-callout to global (*) selector?

Edit: apparently, since it's pointed in the question you're referring to :)

Comment: yes for highlight, no for touch-callout. I'll try but the weird think is this is only when the page is an a web app. I'll try once I got a bit of time (we've a demo i don't want to reset the installation now).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 5):

The combination of `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` and `-webkit-user-select` works for me. You can apply these to an individual element, or `html`.

```css
html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```